GeoServer on multiple app service instances issue
I am running into issues when there is more then one instance of a GeoServer app service running in Azure. I have a feeling it is something to do with the load balancer built into the app service but I am not sure what to change to "fix" it.
I have tried setting the PROXY_BASE_URL to https://oursite.azurewebsites.net/geoserver/ via Environment variable and through the GUI but it did not seem to do anything.
Setting session affinity to On solves the problem too but there are side affects of this setting that seem to negate the whole purpose of going to app-service and from what I have read GeoServer is stateless and this should not be required.

Do you have any suggestions?
GeoServer version 2.25.1.
Java 17
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jdk
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/tomcat/lib/servlet-api.jar:/home/tomcat/lib/azure.appservice.jar:/home/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Using CATALINA_OPTS:   -Xms1500m -Xmx6656m
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS:  --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx5378M -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Options -Xverify:none and -noverify were deprecated in JDK 13 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Server version: Apache Tomcat/9.0.88
Server built:   Apr 9 2024 13:22:30 UTC
Server number:  9.0.88.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     5.15.153.1-2.cm2
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    17.0.11+9-LTS
JVM Vendor:     Microsoft

Other symptoms when Session Affinity is turned off (redirects over and over)

We are trying to run GeoServer in Azure as an App Service. Problems arise when I scale out to more then one instance.
The login page does not work. However GeoServer does still respond to requests on the map and appears to work. When WebUI Mode setting is set to Default I get redirected repeatedly. Here is the network tab 
When WebUI Mode setting is set to DO_NOT_REDIRECT it looks like this
Network tab when WebUI Mode setting is set to DO_NOT_REDIRECT 
The URL I requested:
https://oursite.azurewebsites.net/geoserver/
My understanding is that the load balancer is built into Azure App Service, and it does not seem straight forward to see exactly what it is doing or if that is possible.
Other info that may be helpful


That sounds like everything is working as expected.

So the login page is expected not to work when there is more then 1 instance? I don't understand that. How are you supposed to manage GeoServer if you can't login to the admin panel?

How could it work, each instance has it's own state unless you set don't redirect it could go anywhere. You must have a leader and followers that get updated from the leader or chaos ensues

So would you recommend leaving Session Affinity on? That seems to defeat the whole purpose of putting GeoServer behind a load balancer to me. Even with redirecting off I can't log in to the admin panel unless Session Affinity is on. My understanding is that Session Affinity ties the client to one instance after the first request, so if that instance gets overwhelmed and we scale out, all the clients that were connected to the overwhelmed instance would still be connected to it rather then distributing it to the new instance. I have also read GeoServer is stateless, is this not the case?

Nope, I would log into the lead machine directly using it's local address and make sure no redirect was on so that it didn't forward to the load balancer. You set the proxy to make sure that the get capabilities point to the load balancer all WMS requests are stateless so it's fine.

Sounds like you need to discuss your setup with your supplier if you don't understand how to configure y

Do you think this is something in Tomcat or something in Azure? I am not sure that I can change the load balancer in Azure easily (it is baked into the App Service) but I did reach out to Microsoft to see if they can assist, seems like I might need an Application Gateway. I am wondering in the mean time if this may be something on Tomcat that I can adjust

But it's working as it is supposed to. Just don't login into the gui via the load balancer

I don't believe there is another way to log into the gui

Ssh to the machine with a tunnel to 8080

I am not sure that is possible on Azure App Service but I will try it out
